# Cocoapods install error : 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: “127.0.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods to manager the third parties of my iOS app. Before today, it performed well. But when I tried to install a new third framework named `UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA`, it gave me an error which I cannot figure out the reason, cause when I install other frameworks it all go well. Does anybody know the reason?

[image]

Comment: Can you access that URL `http://dev.umeng.com/system/resources/W1siZiIsIjIwMTcvMDEvMjIvMTFfMDNfMjRfNzM0X3Vtc2RrX0lPU19hbmFseWljc19ub19pZGZhX3Y0LjIuNS56aXAiXV0/umsdk_IOS_analyics_no-idfa_v4.2.5.zip` ? It's the URL for the download of the ressource provided in the podspec (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/3/7/UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA/4.2.5/UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA.podspec.json). You may have an issue about a firewall (VPN? DNS?) that could lead to your issue.

Comment: Yes, I can access this URL in my browser. And I have set the http_proxy in my terminal so I can get through the firewall. But my DNS is automatically assigned to 192.168.18.1 because I am using the inner network of my company.

Comment: And I can get the content of that URL through the ```requests``` library of ```Python3``` in the terminal environment, so is there any possibility that the ```UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA``` itself doesn't support Internet proxy? I have tried to turn off my proxy but it still didn't work.  The only solution I can get now is to install ```UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA``` manually.